# Ruby error using sub method with closure

Tags: ruby, regex

I am not a Ruby developer, but I'm trying to use 1 line of Ruby script to increment a 3-part version number for a Grails application that we're building with Jenkins. The version number is stored in a simple properties file called application.properties. I know there's tons of ways to do this, but my question here is specific to Ruby and why it's not working.

For testing, I reduced application.properties to a single line:

```
app.version=0.2.8
```

All I want to do is increment the last number. That's it. So, I found some code online and hacked it a bit:

```
ruby -pi.bak -e 'sub(/^app\.version=(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(-?\d+)/) { "app.version=#{$1}.#{$2}.#{$3.to_i.next}" }' application.properties
```

This code works perfectly on Ruby 1.8.7 on OS X, but fails on Ruby 1.9.3 on Linux:

```
-e:1:in `sub': wrong number of arguments (1 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
    from -e:1:in `sub'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Note that the expression works on Linux if applied directly to a string literal:

```
ruby -e 'puts "app.version=0.2.8".sub(/^app\.version=(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(-?\d+)/) { "app.version=#{$1}.#{$2}.#{$3.to_i.next}" }'
```

I also tried gsub but that didn't work either (but for a different reason).

I must be missing something simple here. I've tried other examples using a closure with sub() and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Why are you posting ruby code as a string passed to the ruby executable. That's incredibly hard to read. Is this a question about ruby code, or about the command line?

Comment: It's a question about Ruby code that fails on 1.9.3 (Linux) unless applied directly to a string literal, but works perfectly on Ruby 1.8.7 (OS X). I know it's hard to read but that's only because of the regex - it's only 1 method call and 1 line in the closure. (It wasn't my idea to use Ruby for this purpose - I'm just trying to understand the error, and why it works in certain cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since BernardK suggested that not all versions of Ruby treat -p the same, and since my code worked when applied to a string literal, then here is a solution that works on both 1.8.7 and 1.9.3. Create a file called incAppVersion.rb:

```
if $_ =~ /^\s*app\.version\s*=/
    print $_.sub(/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(-?\d+)/) { "#{$1}.#{$2}.#{$3.to_i.next}" }
else
    print $_
end
```

and run it with:

```
ruby -ni.bak incAppVer.rb application.properties
```

-n is cool!

Please feel free to offer suggestions for improvement.

Comment: Really cool ! Rewriting a file without even opening it with `File.open` and doing I don't know what to update it (maybe with rewind and seek). I have searched the Ruby core forum to see if there is a bug for sub in 1.9.3, but the search engine didn't answer precisely to my keywords.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ruby -pi.bak -e'$_.chomp!; $_ = $_[0..-2] + $_[-1, 1].succ + "\n" if $_[0..11] == "app.version="' application.properties
```

As the Pickaxe(*) explains for -p : *Places your program code within the loop* `while gets; ...; print; end`.

`gets` puts the line just read into `$_`.
`chomp!` removes CRLF.
`print` without arguments prints `$_`, thus we must modify $_ : `$_ = ...`
`$_[0..-2]` is the input line except the last character
`$_[-1, 1]` is the last character, for a length one (needed in Ruby 1.8 to get a char, not a number)
`$_[-1, 1].succ` is the next character/number
`+ "\n"` to put CRLF again (change it to "\r\n" on Windows)
`if $_[0..11] == "app.version="` to process only the desired property

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

Tested on OS X ML.
File before :

```
app.version=0.2.8
line2
```

File after two executions :

```
app.version=0.2.10
line2
```

(*) http://pragprog.com/book/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, but I really wanted to find out why my script works in certain cases but not in others. Also, strangely, using your script, the CRLF was not added back in on 1.9.3 (ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [i686-linux]) nor on OS X where I'm still on 1.8.7. 

We already have something else in place that is working, but I still don't understand why 1.9.3 spits out that error. 

Maybe I should just delete my post and forget about it. I've wasted enough time on this as it is.

Comment: I have learned something on parameters -p and -i. It seems that various versions are not the same, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080897/interesting-bug-in-osx-preinstalled-ruby-1-8-7