# Ruby Command Line Options - verbose mode ON and placing code into Imput Loop

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

Can any body tell how the below three options differs from each other in Ruby?

***Part-I***

- **--verbose**
- **-v**
- **-w**

***Part-II***

- -**n**
- -**p**

All are doing the same job which is `verbose` mode `ON`. But logically how are they differs from each other?

Thanks,

Comment: Recent question using -n -p http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075289/ruby-error-using-sub-method-with-closure/14076895

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-v` is just a shorter way of writing `--verbose`, so they are the same thing. `-w` turns on warnings, see http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml#warnings for more info about those.

Part 2:

`-n` and `-p` are not related to verbosity. They just loop your ruby script.

Run the following from your terminal:

```
ruby -n -e "puts 'hello world'"
```

Now press the enter key a few times. You should see:

```
hello world

hello world

hello world
```

Now do the same for `-p`:

```
ruby -p -e "puts 'hello world'"
```

This just repeats what you typed before pressing enter.

```
asdf
hello world
asdf

hello world

asdfs
hello world
asdfs
34644
hello world
34644
```

Comment: Yeah I just updated description of my code. `part-I` is clear to me. and what about `part-II` ?

Comment: Answer updated. Note that I've never seen the `-n` or `-p` options used.

Comment: Thanks for your help and clarifications,`+1` to you!Nice to meet with you on `SO` :)

Comment: Seldom, but not never :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075289/ruby-error-using-sub-method-with-closure/14076895

Comment: @nathan.f77 what the number `34644` is BTW? with `-n` option why `hello world` came only three times?

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU - 34644 is just a random number I typed in. and `hello world` only came 3 times because I pressed enter 3 times.